# C# remove directory from the file path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I need to remove the drive from the filepath

```
string fileName = "c:\Import\Customers\2745"
```

I need to remove the `"c:\"` from the string `"Import\Customer\2745"`

I tired using `File.GetFileName` but it does not do the same

Is there a generic function for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried [sic] using File.Path but it does not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getpathroot?view=net-6.0):

> Gets the root directory information from the path contained in the specified string.

Then use the length of the value returned to call [`String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0), something like this:

```
string fileName = @"c:\Import\Customers\2745"

string withoutDriveLetter = fileName.Substring(Path.GetPathRoot(fileName).Length);

// will display "Import\Customers\2745":
Console.WriteLine(withoutDriveLetter);
```